# Simple Two wire SPI communication between two PIC24s

Tags: pic, communication, spi

I am trying to achieve a simple *SPI communication of 16-bit data* from a *PIC24FJ64GA002* to another of the same microcontroller.
By following the data sheet to the word, I wrote the transmitter and receiver code as below,

**Transmitter:**

```
unsigned int i = 0;

void main()
{
    RPOR2bits.RP4R = 7;  // Data out through Peripheral Pin 4
    RPOR2bits.RP5R = 8;  // Clock out  through Peripheral Pin 5
    SPI1CON1bits.MODE16 = 1; //16 bit mode 
    SPI1CON1bits.MSTEN = 1;  // Master enable
    SPI1CON1bits.SSEN = 0; //No slave selection
    SPI1STATbits.SPIROV = 0; //Receiver Overflow cleared as told in datasheet
    SPI1STATbits.SPIEN = 1; //SPI is enabled
    while (1)
    {
        while (SPI1STATbits.SPITBF); //Waiting for any transmission to complete
        SPI1BUF = i; // Data is written
        i++
    }
}
```

**Receiver:**

```
unsigned int i;

void main()
{
    RPINR20bits.SDI1R = 0; //Data in through Peripheral pin 0
    RPINR20bits.SCK1R = 2; //Clock in through Peripheral pin 2
    AD1PCFG = 0xFFFF;
    TRISA = 0x0000;
    SPI1CON1bits.MODE16 = 1;
    SPI1CON1bits.MSTEN = 0; // Slave mode
    SPI1CON1bits.SSEN = 0;
    SPI1CON1bits.SMP = 0; //Must be cleared in slave mode as told in datasheet
    SPI1CON1bits.DISSDO = 1; //Receiver only receives data
    SPI1STATbits.SPIROV = 0;
    SPI1STATbits.SPIEN = 1;

    while (1)
    {
        while (!SPI1STATbits.SPIRBF); //waiting for receive to complete
        LATA = SPI1BUF; // pushing Received data onto A
    }
}
```

The transmitter seems to be transmitting the data (clock and data lines show expected cycles), but for some reason the receiver does not receive the data and push it onto A terminals.

The **configuration settings** for both microcontrollers are:

```
Primary Oscillator Select: Primary Oscillator Disabled 
I2c1 Pin Location Select: Use default SCL 1/SDA 1 pins 
IOLOCK Protection: Disabled 
OSCO Pin Configuration: OSCO functions as port I/O 
Clock Switching and Monitor: Clock switching is enabled, Fail-safe Clock Monitor is enabled 
Oscillator Select: Fast RC Oscillator (FRC) 
Sec Oscillator Select: Default Secondary Oscillator (SOSC) 
Wake-up timer Select: Legacy Wake-up Timer 
Internal External Switch Over Mode: Disabled
External Watchdog Timer Postscaler: 1:32,768
WDT Prescalar: Prescaler ratio of 1:128 
Watchdog Timer Window: Disabled 
Watchdog Timer Enable: Disabled 
Comm Channel Select: Emulator EMUC1/EMUD1 pins are shared with PGC1/PGD1 
Background Debug: Disabled 
General Code Segment Write Protect: Disabled 
General Code Segment Code Protect: Disabled 
JTAG Port Enable: Disabled
```

The only two connections are the Clock and data lines from the respective peripheral pins. What is the problem here and how to receive the data?

It seems impossible that this actually works, has anybody ever achieved this?

Comment: Check SPI chip select is pulled up to logic 1, and is asserted to 0 correctly during comms.

Comment: @Oliver If you mean Slave Select, I have disabled it by specifying SPI1CON1bits.SSEN=0; (which is default), but it still does not solve the problem.

Comment: I meant slave select, yes. Every device has it's on name for it. I see the master is set to not assert a SS/CS signal, is the slave also set to not expect it?

Also what speed is the SPI running at? Have you scoped the data and clock lines to see how they look?

Comment: Yes the line SPI1CON1bits.SSEN=0; specifically disabling the chip select is written in both transmitter and receiver code. It still doesnt help. The presecalar setting are left to default values so the secondary prescalar is 8:1 and the primary is 64:1 running using the internal FRC oscillator at 10 MHz.
Everything is left to its default values, because I want the simplest SPI code unfortunately it isn't working. The transmitter output is (by waveforms it outputs) consistent. The receiver is not able to receive or render that data into the output port.

Comment: Which line is it in the receiver code? Not to labour the point, but I can't see where SS is disabled in the receive code.

Comment: No I added it now to see if it changes anything but it does not.

Comment: That's a shame, would have been a easy fix. Are you able to (have access to) see the output waveforms on an oscilioscope?

Comment: In any case all bit values are by default 0 unless or otherwise specified right? 

Well I transmit 0 and the data line stays low and for any other values its expected waveforms. The circuit hasn't yet worked out in simulation, so I haven't yet taken it to hardware. I am using Proteus and it's always been fairly accurate.

Comment: @Oliver I am new to stackexchange and I don't know if this is acceptable but if you wish I can send you the entire Mikro C program along with the simulation file. There might be things that are important that I have not said here.

Comment: I think your problem is the SS pin. Without it the slave is getting the data into its shift register but it doesn't transfer it to the FIFO.

Comment: @Alex
I changed SSEN to 1 in both receiver and transmitter.
Added this line to the transmitter: RPOR1bits.RP3R =9;
and to receiver: RPINR21bits.SS1R=1;

 I connected RP3 of transmitter to RP1 of receiver and the line is not active at all (Proteus shows an active line as either high or low) and the communication does not happen too.

Comment: Can anybody mail me an example SPI code that achieves communication between 2 PIC24 microcontrollers? There seems to be no reference for me to refer.
hp07@india.com

Comment: In looking over the code, I notice there is a "!" in the receiver while statement which is not found in the transmitter while statement.

Comment: @Guill Well it is dependent on the nature of the bit. In case of the transmitter the bit is cleared after transmission is complete while in a receiver the bit is set after reception is complete.

Comment: @Harsha: I recommend putting debug code between the statements while and LATA as follows: -display message ("read data, press tab to continue")  -wait (for tab press).

Comment: If the message displays, the while statement is working OK!

Comment: @Guill how exactly can i add the debug code in MikroC? And I don't understand what you mean by tab.

Comment: If you are not going to use a slave select line, you you need incorporate either a time- or data- based method of detecting the start of a new transmission in order to achieve synchronization.  Otherwise you system will depend on startup order, and once mis-synchronized will have no way to correct for that.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning pins to peripherals incorrectly. Simply setting the bit is not enough, you must follow an unlock sequence at least once, and it is recommended to lock the register after you're done with assignment. The useful macros are contained in 'pps.h', the code will look like that (for UART2):

```
PPSUnLock;
PPSOutput( PPS_RP21, PPS_U2TX );
PPSInput( PPS_U2RX, PPS_RP26 );
```

The whole C file can be seen here -> https://github.com/felis/cdb/blob/master/fw/minimal/bsp.c#L185

Comment: If that was the problem then there would be no transmission at all but there are changes that occur in the output and also the first transmission happens successfully.